# Group by a query from a view which is already grouped

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-view

A simple question, is this possible to make a group by from a select from a view?
Scenario: I have a view which gives me generation, nº, biomass, av.weight and date. I want to group by generation this select

```
    select * from View where date => my_date and date <= my_date
```

I've tried something like

```
   select generation, nº, biomass, av.weight from select * from View where date => my_date and date <= my_date group by generation
```

But it doesn't seem to work... :/

Of course I can just make the query and then deal with results on the Java Code but it would be better if I could retrieve directly what I want from SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

EDIT: As my question is kinda confusing I will try to re-formulate it. I've created a view as:

```
    SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Generacion.descgeneracion,      SUM(dbo.MovimientosEstanque.numeroindividuos) AS numeroindividuos, 
                     SUM(dbo.MovimientosEstanque.pesomedio * dbo.MovimientosEstanque.numeroindividuos / 1000) AS biomasa, 
                     SUM(dbo.MovimientosEstanque.pesomedio * dbo.MovimientosEstanque.numeroindividuos / 1000) * 1000 / SUM(dbo.MovimientosEstanque.numeroindividuos) AS pesomedio, dbo.MovimientosEstanque.fechamovimiento AS fecha, dbo.LoteDePlanta.codigoplanta FROM            dbo.MovimientosEstanque INNER JOIN
                     dbo.CicloProductivo ON dbo.CicloProductivo.codigociclo = dbo.MovimientosEstanque.codigocicloorigen INNER JOIN
                     dbo.LoteDePlanta ON dbo.CicloProductivo.idloteplanta = dbo.LoteDePlanta.idloteplanta INNER JOIN  dbo.Generacion ON dbo.Generacion.idgeneracion = dbo.LoteDePlanta.idgeneracion WHERE        (dbo.MovimientosEstanque.idtipomovimiento = 'SAL') GROUP BY dbo.Generacion.descgeneracion, dbo.MovimientosEstanque.fechamovimiento, dbo.LoteDePlanta.codigoplanta ORDER BY dbo.Generacion.descgeneracion
```

Now, user will enter a range of dates (let's say for example 20140707 and 20140709) and I must show "numeroindividuos", "biomasa" and "pesomedio" grouped by generation for those days. So for instance when I execute:

```
select descgeneracion, numeroindividuos, biomasa, pesomedio, fecha from VistaDespesquesGeneraciones where fecha  >= '20140707' and fecha <= '20140710'
```

I get:

```
descgeneracion           numeroindividuos biomasa                pesomedio              fecha
14 4                    76189            892422                 11713,2656945228       2014-07-07 00:00:00.000
14 4                     39410            80172079               2034308,01826947       2014-07-08 00:00:00.000
14 4                     1410             115476                 81897,8723404255       2014-07-10 00:00:00.000
```

Now I want to group those results by generation so I could get something like

```
descgeneration numeroindividuos       biomasa       pesomedio
14 4           SUM(numeroindividuos) SUM(biomasa) SUM(pesomedio)
```

I've tried

```
select descgeneracion, sum(numeroindividuos), sum(biomasa), sum(pesomedio) from select * from VistaDespesquesGeneraciones where fecha >= '20140707' and fecha <= '20140709' group by descgeneracion
```

and

```
select descgeneracion, sum(numeroindividuos), sum(biomasa), sum(pesomedio) from [select * from VistaDespesquesGeneraciones where fecha >= '20140707' and fecha <= '20140709'] group by descgeneracion
```

None of them worked, sintax error first case and object name not valid on second case.

Sorry for the misuderstanding.

Comment: Why do you want to group by generation? do you want to pick counts or sum of a column?

Comment: You'll have to use parentheses to make the view a subselect. And you can't just `GROUP BY` one column, you'll have to use Aggregate functions on the other columns, or also group by them

Comment: @NickyvV I am afraid parentheses is not working it returns that the name object 'select * from VistaDespesquesGeneraciones where fecha >= '20140707' and fecha <= '20140707' is not valid

Comment: @mhn I am gonna edit my question to try to be more clear

Comment: @Santi You're using brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()`. Or have a look at the answer of @Nothingman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the subquery on the view in brackets. That way it will be treated as its own table. As an example using the code above;

```
 select a.generation, count(*) as [nº], a.biomass, a.weight from (select generation, <uniquekey>, biomass, weight from View where date => my_date and date <= my_date) a group by a.generation, a.biomass, a.weight
```

Alternatively do this without using a subquery (this may return a slightly faster result)

```
select generation, count(*) as [nº], biomass, weight from View where date => my_date and date <= my_date group by generation, biomass, weight
```

Any of the values not calculated by a count, max, min ect need to be included though, so you would need to decide how the weight and biomass would be calculated out (min, max, average). See mxix's answer as an example.

Edit: same theory as above with the new example code.

```
select a.descgeneracion, sum(a.numeroindividuos), sum(a.biomasa), sum(a.pesomedio) from (select descgeneracion, numeroindividuos, biomasa, pesomedio from VistaDespesquesGeneraciones where fecha >= '20140707' and fecha <= '20140709') a group by a.descgeneracion
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that I should cast the select so I could access to the values of it like a.*.

Beginner errors -.-

Answer (score 0):

Next time try to post the error you are getting, usually helps.

Avoid using `select *` it help to know the schema.

Since i don't know the fields, i'm going to have to assume.

```
select generation, COUNT(*) [nº], SUM(weight) [biomass], AVG(weight) [av.weight] from (select * from View where date => my_date and date <= my_date) t group by generation
```

With [group by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) the other field that are not included in the group by clause must be affected by some kind of [Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)